# Покажите пример добавления произвольному классу поддержки IInterface: например, для TList или TThread, TListBox

Tags: delphi

Покажите пример добавления произвольному классу поддержки IInterface: например, для TList или TThread, TListBox.
Я всегда делал это через делегирование новому TInterfacedObject, в котором одно из полей - мой класс, но это меня изрядно замотало в клубок. Просто, я смотрю на TInterfacedObject и не могу понять, нужно ли  всё оттуда скопировать, чтобы  все нормально работало

```
 
 type 
IList = interface
  procedure Method1;
  procedure Method2;
end;
TMyListBox = class(TListBox,IList)
  
  procedure Method1;
  procedure Method2;
  ??? ну так не работает addref нужен и еще что то

end;
```

Comment: методы интерфейса своего туда добавьте и все дела

Comment: @teran TListBox не поддерживает интерфейс ему нужно еше методы кроме моих (стандартные для I ) прописать

Comment: ну продублируйте то что есть в TInterfacedObject. Вам нужны QueryInterface, _AddRef, and _Release.  доки - https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Implementing_Interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Если речь конкретно про `TListBox` и подобные визуальные компоненты, то они все унаследованы от класса `TComponent`, который уже реализует `IInterface` также как и `TInterfacedObject`.

То, что приведено в вопросе уже достаточно.

Если что-то не работает, укажите конкретную версию Delphi

Comment: я просто тупень писать вопросы ночью после тяжелого дня. я удалю вопрос.